# Как использовать OpenGL совместно с SDL2?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("title", 0, 0, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_GLContext glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    glClearColor(0, 0xFF, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    while (true)
    {
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(glcontext);
    return 0;
}
```

Без строк `glClearColor(0, 0xFF, 0, 1);` и `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` программа собирается и запускается, с ними "ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ".
Возможно ли только с sdl2 без других библиотек использовать opengl3 и свежее?